# Twilio REST API filter parameter with multiple values

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Is it possible to filter the twilio REST API with multiple values supplied in a single request for the same parameter?

I am wanting to collect all of the phone numbers that twilio is currently calling out to. Based on the documentation that appears to be any call with a current status of 'queued', 'ringing', or 'in-progress'.

Using the SDK, I have attempted to string the query parameters like so:

```
$twilio->calls->read(array("status" => "queued", "status" => "ringing", "status" => "in-progress"));
```

However, this only returns the last status supplied in the array - in this case "in-progress".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio API cannot be filtered with multiple values supplied in a single request. You will need to make multiple requests I'm afraid.